# Any idea why org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap pops up in dock on Mac?

Tags: macos, tomcat

I have a web application setup using tomcat. Sometimes a little icon appears in the dock with the title "org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap".

Does anyone know why this happens and/OR how to fix this ?

Tomcat Version : 7.0.19

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found this incredibly annoying too, it would always steal focus from my web browser after I restarted Tomcat via Eclipse.

To fix it I went to the folder containing the Tomcat instance Eclipse was using (for me it was /Servers/Tomcat_Blah_Blah_Blah)

Edit catalina.properties and add a line with "java.awt.headless=true"

Comment: This worked great.  My Tomcat instance is managed through Eclipse, so the next time I restarted Eclipse, that property was lost.  That was easy to fix, though.  I just opened the catalina.properties associated with the server within the Eclipse "Servers" pseudo-project, added the property, saved it, and all is well now.

Comment: This still happens in the latest Tomcat (8.0.9.)  The Bootstrap appears on OS X Mavericks as soon as you access one of the websocket examples (e.g. http://localhost:8008/examples/websocket/snake.xhtml)

Comment: or you can pass `-Djava.awt.headless=true` as a VM option in eclipse/idea

Answer (score 0):

I tried this approach and it worked for me
I guess it might be a packaging issue.

To work it around, you need to add the tomcat-juli.jar to the run configuration class path.

Here are the steps how to do it:
In Eclipse, Open the "Server" tab. Double click on the "Tomcat6" .You can
see the configuration details there.Under the General Information block click 
on Open Launch configuration.In the dialog box select the "Classpath" tab.
Click on "Add external jar" button.Select the tomcat-juli.jar file under tomcat6/bin.Close the dialog box and restart the eclipse.